# Firebase Cloud Messaging Unsubscribe from all topics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a simple news app for my college. To send notifications, I use firebase cloud messaging

My problem: I want to send notifications based on the version of my app from the API. when my app version is 2. I will send a notification to the topic v2. but when users update the app to v3 and I need to maintain v2 of my app then how can I target v3 only

Comment: As of today I don't think there's an API which unsubscribes from all previously subscribed topics. You might want to use a persistent data layer to store the current app topic so that when user upgrades you can look it up and then do what's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use a `condition`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-topics) to send to folks who have only subscribed to v2 and not v3.

```
condition: "'v2' in topics && !'v3' in topics"
```

Note that this allows up to 5 clauses only, so I'd recommend also updating the logic in your app to remove subscriptions to older versions. You don't even need to do this conditionally, so it can be as simple as:

```
Firebase.messaging.subscribeToTopic("v3");
Firebase.messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic("v2");
Firebase.messaging.unsubscribeFromTopic("v1");
```

If the user is not/no longer subscribed to a topic, calling `unsubscribeFromTopic` doesn't do anything (but doesn't fail).